# Drag n' Drop File Upload

Tags: jquery, html, filereader

I have a web app that allows a user to double-click a DIV / placeholder, which in turn, brings up the browser upload dialogue.  After choosing an image, I use `FileReader` to read the image, and display it in the specified placeholder.

I'd like to add a drag n' drop component to this.  I've looked into Dropzone and other scripts, but they all seem to do too much.  I just need to be able to drop an image in the specified area, and somehow, hook into the browser's basic file-upload, as though the image were being uploaded in the traditional sense.  And then, I could just pass it along to the rest of my code as usual.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
// This is within an updateImage() function which gets triggered by a user
// double-clicking a Div / image placeholder

    this.file = $('<input type="file" />');
    this.file.trigger('click');

    //keep a reference to this so that closures can use it
    var that = this;
    this.file.on('change', function(event) {
        var f = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(inner_event) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function() {
                // Get all the Image info
                that.user_image = inner_event.target.result;
```

and then after some processing and storing of data / CSS...

```
reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with.  Essentially, I access the `dblclick` and `drop` events:

```
// TheImageElement is a placeholder DIV

this.dom_element.on('drop', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    that.updateImage(evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);
});


this.dom_element.on('dblclick', function() {
    that.handleImageUpload();
});
```

The `dblclick` event calls `handleImageUpload()` which triggers the File `<input>`:

```
this.ImageElement.prototype.handleImageUpload = function() {
    this.file = $('<input type="file" />');
    this.file.trigger('click');

    //keep a reference to this so that closures can use it
    var that = this;
    this.file.on('change', function(event) {
        that.updateImage(event.target.files[0]);
    });
}
```

And now, both methods call the updateImage() method, and pass along the File:

```
this.ImageElement.prototype.updateImage = function(theFile) {
    new_upload = true;
    // keep a reference to this so that closures can use it
    var that = this;
    var f = theFile;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(inner_event) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {

              // Some processing here
        }
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

So now, the File Upload can be accessed by both the traditional double-click, and the drag-drop, using the same code to process them.